# Residuals from first differenced regression on unbalanced panel

Tags: r, output, panel-data, plm

I am trying to use plm to estimate a first differenced model on some unbalanced panel data. My model seems to work and I get coefficient estimates, but I want to know if there is a way to get the residual (or fitted value) per observation used.

I have run into two problems, I don't know how to attach residuals to the observation they are associated with, and I seem to get an incorrect number of residuals.

If I retrieve the residuals from the estimated model using model.name$residuals, I get a vector that is shorter than model.name$model.

```
require(plm)
X <- rnorm(14)
Y <- c(.4,1,1.5,1.3,1,4,5,6.5,7.3,3.7,5,.7,4,6)
Time <- rep(1:5,times=2)
Time <- c(Time, c(1,2,4,5))
ID <- rep(1:2,each=5)
ID <- c(ID,c(3,3,3,3))
TestData <- data.frame("Y"=Y,"X"=X,"ID"=ID,"Time"=Time)
model.name <- plm(Y~X,data=TestData,index = c("ID","Time"),model="fd")

> length(model.name$residuals)
[1] 11
> nrow(model.name$model)
[1] 14
```

(Note: ID=3 is missing an observation for t=3)

Looking at model.name$model I see it includes all observations, including t=1 for each member of ID. In the first differencing the t=1 observations will be removed, so in this case both IDs with all time periods should have 4 residuals from the remaining time periods. ID=3 should have a residual for t=2, none for t=3 as it is missing, none for t=4 as there is no value to difference (due to the missing t=3 value) and then a residual for t=5.

From this it seems that there should be 10 residuals, but I have 11. I would appreciate any help with why there are this many residuals, and how to connect residuals to the correct index (ID and Time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lagging done with `model="fd"` is based on the neighbouring rows, not the actual value of the time index. Thus, if you have non-consecutive time periods, this will give you unexpected results. To avoid this, do the differencing yourself while respecting the time period when lagging and estimate a **pooling** model. The unbalancedness of the data is not of concern here.

Since version 1.7.0 of package `plm`, there `lag()` function performs lagging based on the value of the time period per default (previous default was neighboring rows). Use this function to do the lagging yourself.

Continuing your example:

```
pTestData <- pdata.frame(TestData, index=c("ID", "Time"))

pTestData$Y_diff <- plm::lag(pTestData$Y) - pTestData$Y
pTestData$X_diff <- plm::lag(pTestData$X) - pTestData$X
fdmod <- plm(Y_diff ~ X_diff, data = pTestData, model = "pooling")
length(residuals(fdmod)) # 10
nrow(fdmod$model)        # 10
```

I explicity used `plm::` when referring to the lag function as several other packages have a lag function as well (most notably `stats` and `dplyr`) and you want to use the one from package plm here.
To augment the residuals to the differenced data (actually used for computing the model), just do something like:
`dat <- cbind(fdmod$model, residuals(fdmod))`

Also, you might be interested in the function `is.pconsecutive`
to check for consectutiveness of your data:

```
is.pconsecutive(pTestData)
#    1     2     3 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Function `make.pconsecutive` will make your data consecutive by inserting rows with `NA` values for the missing period.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful and answers the question. This might be more appropriate as a new question, but do you have a suggestion as to how to resolve the same issue when using plm with "fd" and IVs, or when using pgmm?