# Does first-difference work on unbalanced data with holes in plm?

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

On page 423 in [Computational Laboratory for Economics](https://books.google.ca/books?id=5UMrAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA423&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false), it is stated that "the argument `model="fd"` doesn't work correctly, with the current version (1.3-1) of `plm`, on unbalanced data with holes." Has this been fixed in the newer versions of `plm`?

As a workaround, the author used `diff` to obtain the first differences and fitted a `model="pooling"`on the differenced data. Can someone explain how the `diff` function works on unbalanced data with holes?

Also, on page 68 in the [plm documenation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf) version (1.6-5), it is stated that
"plm is a general function for the estimation of linear panel models. It supports the following estimation methods: pooled OLS (model = "pooling"), fixed effects ("within"), random effects ("random"), first–differences ("fd"), and between ("between"). It supports unbalanced panels and two–way effects (although not with all methods)."

Comment: Your question about how `plm` handles FD models and how to treat gaps is answered in detail in this two answers:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364471/residuals-from-first-differenced-regression-on-unbalanced-panel/39378265#39378265  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926625/r-plm-lag-what-is-the-equivalent-to-l1-x-in-stata/43932317#43932317

Comment: So, using the `diff` function on unbalanced data with holes wouldn't really work - rather it should be something like `pTestData$Y_diff <-
 plm:::lagt.pseries(pTestData$Y) - pTestData$Y` as in your other answer, right?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why the authors of that text book came up with the idea of `diff` (this could either be `base::diff` or `plm::diff` and both give row-wise differences, the latter respecting the panel structure of the data).

Comment: So, bottom line, `model="fd"`should not be used with unbalanced data. `plm:::lagt.pseries` works for both balanced and unbalanced panel data.

Comment: It is not about the unbalancedness, that works fine. It is about gaps in the time dimensions as the standard way is diff-ing of neighbouring rows per individual (taking the panel structure into account). Use `is.pconsecutive` to check for any gaps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a predict function for PLM in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123060/is-there-a-predict-function-for-plm-in-r)

Comment: @Helix123, this could be a separate question and I am happy to do so.
when comparing the fd and pooling models on the data and the differenced data as we discussed, I get the same results as expected but not always!
My data is indexed as a panel by ids and serial time variable which combines month and year. In the model, I add month and year dummies to control for seasonality and trend. In this example, the results of the two models (fd/pooling) are dramatically different when I add the year dummies. Any idea why?